# CSS - make height of the image to be auto stretched within a container of fixed height

Tags: html, css

I tried with following solution:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-nXak3-M8QG4/ULtEsnBI0RI/AAAAAAAAAOA/7uEYy1oExZc/s1600/black-desktop-computer.jpg"/>
 </div>
```

here is css:

```
img {
    width:120px;
    height: auto;
}

.item {
    border:1px solid pink;
    width: 120px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Please take a look of this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/it_sand/9ffos3f6/) to see the output.

There is a extra bottom space. I want to remove that extra space. I tried with many combinations but no success.

Any other solution would be preferred. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, here is [another solution](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/)
by using object-fit property

Comment: I have an image to which I was adding a 10px border to... when the image was resized down (by its bounding div) the height was wrong (set to 'auto'). This is the only solution I have found that works for me. Thanks Nick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 img {
        width:120px;
        height: 100%;
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .item {
        border:1px solid pink;
        width: 120px;
        height: 100px;
      display: table;
        margin: 3px;
        padding: 3px;
        background-color: red;
    }
```

Please let me know if this is what you wnated.

Answer (score 0):

This space is for [descenders](http://www.typographydeconstructed.com/descender/), you see it because images are laid out as text. Just add `display: block;` or `vertical-align: bottom;` to make it disappear.